# For cycle in R Shiny

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, shiny, cycle

I am trying to create an app in Shiny that receives an input in a certain way and return an input. The code should work as follows:

The input is a table, called trips made in this way:

```
>head(trips)
  time.start   time.end long.start long.end lat.start  lat.end
1 1476450598 1476450713    9.03913  9.03924  45.61335 45.61362
2 1476450713 1476450727    9.03924  9.03995  45.61362 45.61365
3 1476450727 1476450751    9.03995  9.04005  45.61365 45.61340
4 1476450751 1476450777    9.04005  9.04017  45.61340 45.61406
5 1476450777 1476450873    9.04017  9.03949  45.61406 45.61419
6 1476450873 1476450920    9.03949  9.03496  45.61419 45.61319
```

and the manipulation is as follows (in standard R environment)

```
for (i in 1:dim(trips)[1]){
  trips$distance[i]<-as.numeric(distm(c(trips$long.start[i],trips$lat.start[i]), c(trips$long.end[i],trips$lat.end[i]), fun = distHaversine))
  trips$time.diff[i]<-as.numeric(difftime(anytime(trips$time.end[i]),anytime(trips$time.start[i])),units="secs")
  trips$speed[i]<-if (trips$distance[i] ==0) {0} else{
    (trips$distance[i]/as.numeric(difftime(anytime(trips$time.end[i]),                                                            anytime(trips$time.start[i])),units="secs"))*3.6}
  trips$color[i]<-if(trips$speed[i] < 50){"green"} else if (trips$speed[i] < 70){"yellow"}else if (trips$speed[i] > 70){"red"}
}
```

With the relative output:

```
> head(trips)
  time.start   time.end long.start long.end lat.start  lat.end  distance time.diff      speed color
1 1476450598 1476450713    9.03913  9.03924  45.61335 45.61362  31.25292       115  0.9783524 green
2 1476450713 1476450727    9.03924  9.03995  45.61362 45.61365  55.38651        14 14.2422459 green
3 1476450727 1476450751    9.03995  9.04005  45.61365 45.61340  28.89870        24  4.3348057 green
4 1476450751 1476450777    9.04005  9.04017  45.61340 45.61406  74.06267        26 10.2548313 green
5 1476450777 1476450873    9.04017  9.03949  45.61406 45.61419  54.89125        96  2.0584219 green
6 1476450873 1476450920    9.03949  9.03496  45.61419 45.61319 369.88687        47 28.3317600 green
```

As you can see it's nothing that fancy, although in R Shiny doesn't work as expected. Here there is the code:

The first part is to acquire the initial trips table, and everything works smoothly

```
trips<-reactive({
    data.frame(
    time.start=as.numeric((substr(do.call(rbind,lapply(lapply(res.clean()[,2],fromJSON),function(x) x[,1:2]))$recorded_at,1,10)))[1:(length(do.call(rbind,lapply(lapply(res.clean()[,2],fromJSON),function(x) x[,1:2]))$recorded_at)-1)],
    time.end=as.numeric((substr(do.call(rbind,lapply(lapply(res.clean()[,2],fromJSON),function(x) x[,1:2]))$recorded_at,1,10)))[2:(length(do.call(rbind,lapply(lapply(res.clean()[,2],fromJSON),function(x) x[,1:2]))$recorded_at))],
    long.start=matrix((as.vector(unlist(do.call(rbind,lapply(lapply(res.clean()[,2],fromJSON),function(x) x[,1:2]))$loc, recursive = TRUE))),ncol=2,byrow=T)[1:dim(do.call(rbind,lapply(lapply(res.clean()[,2],fromJSON),function(x) x[,1:2])))[1]-1,1],
    long.end=matrix((as.vector(unlist(do.call(rbind,lapply(lapply(res.clean()[,2],fromJSON),function(x) x[,1:2]))$loc, recursive = TRUE))),ncol=2,byrow=T)[2:dim(do.call(rbind,lapply(lapply(res.clean()[,2],fromJSON),function(x) x[,1:2])))[1],1],
    lat.start=matrix((as.vector(unlist(do.call(rbind,lapply(lapply(res.clean()[,2],fromJSON),function(x) x[,1:2]))$loc, recursive = TRUE))),ncol=2,byrow=T)[1:dim(do.call(rbind,lapply(lapply(res.clean()[,2],fromJSON),function(x) x[,1:2])))[1]-1,2],
    lat.end=matrix((as.vector(unlist(do.call(rbind,lapply(lapply(res.clean()[,2],fromJSON),function(x) x[,1:2]))$loc, recursive = TRUE))),ncol=2,byrow=T)[2:dim(do.call(rbind,lapply(lapply(res.clean()[,2],fromJSON),function(x) x[,1:2])))[1],2]
  )[-(cumsum(sapply(lapply(res.clean()[,2],fromJSON), dim)[1,])),]
  })
```

Now I should write the equivalent of the for cycle in the previous section:

```
trips1<-reactive({

  for (i in 1:dim(trips())[1])

    {
    trips1()$distance[i]<-as.numeric(distm(c(trips()$long.start[i],trips()$lat.start[i]), c(trips()$long.end[i],trips()$lat.end[i]), fun = distHaversine))
    trips1()$time.diff[i]<-as.numeric(difftime(anytime(trips()$time.end[i]),anytime(trips()$time.start[i])),units="secs")
    trips1()$speed[i]<-if (trips()$distance[i] ==0) {0} else{
      (trips1()$distance[i]/as.numeric(difftime(anytime(trips()$time.end[i]),
                                             anytime(trips()$time.start[i])),units="secs"))*3.6}
    trips1()$color[i]<-if(trips()$speed[i] < 50){"green"} else if (trips()$speed[i] < 70){"yellow"}else if (trips()$speed[i] > 70){"red"}
  }

})
```

I had to call this function trips1 otherwise it would get confused with the previous trips function. And finally:

```
output$table <- renderTable(trips1())
```

The problem is that I am getting this error

```
invalid (NULL) left side of assignment
```

Is there anything that I am missing?

Thanks for your help

Comment: youre recursively calling trips1. everytime you are using `trips1()` it is running the reactive function. reactives dont work that way.  when youre  calling `renderTable(trips1())` its more or less calling `renderTable(trips1(trips1(trips1(...))))`

Comment: Thanks for this, how can I change the code to make it work?

Comment: try something like : `triploop<-reactive({ tmptrips <- trips()                       for (i in 1:dim(tmptrips)[1])

    {
    tmptrips$distance[i]<-as.numeric(distm(c(tmptrips ...` call trips and populate the tmptrips variable, use tmptrips where youre trying to use trips1() and trips() in the loop. use `tripsresults <- triploop()` to call the looping reactive